# Java is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, path, classpath

So guys I have a huuuuuge problem.

I downloaded java jdk 1.8.0_45.

It was working fine , but because I was making a Runescape Private Server I had to put in my classpath and path in my environmental variables. I did that and when I tried to open java then it said :

> java is not recognized as an internal or external command

so I figured the classpath and path were wrong.
But they weren't , I put them in like this.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin

I checked the folders and that is exactly the correct classpath.
I tried deleting the classpath and path after to restore it back to normal but that didn't work , it kept saying that java is not recognized. I restarted my pc and even did a system restore but nothing worked.

NEED HELP.

Comment: Your path is incorrect for sure. And this isn't about programming, your question is close to be closed.

Answer (score 4):

set JAVA_HOME=path\to\java-dir upto jdk

set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 0):

go to system environment and set you path and class path properly, and it should work. If still have issues, restart the application.

you can also open command prompt after you have set the path, and type in javac to see if the path is set properly or not.